# How do I allow a user to edit a specific column only?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a protected range but I want to do the opposite of its function. I only want a user to be edit that specific range.

So, how can I have them "view only" for the whole spreadsheet but edit one specific range?

Answer (score 6):

Protect the sheet and apply an exception.

1. Right click the sheet's tab
2. Select protect
3. On the sidebar, mark the checkbox "Except certain cells". This will display a field to set the cells that will be editable
4. Click on the button "Set permissions"